# Differential-geometry, regular C^k curves

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $c$ be a regular $C^k$ curve, which is not necessarily path parameterized. Show, that
>
> $T(t)=\frac{\dot{c}(t)}{||\dot{c}(t)||}$, $N(t)=\frac{\dot{T}(t)}{||\dot{T}(t)||}, \kappa(t)=\frac{||\dot{T}(t)||}{||\dot{c}(t)||}$

Hello,

I struggle to show the results above. I think once I have the first one correct, the others might be easy.

I tried this:

Let $c:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a regular $C^k$ curve. Hence it exists a $C^k$ parameterization $\varphi:[0,l]\to[a,b]$, such that $\stackrel{\sim}{c}:=c\circ\varphi$ is path parameterized.

The formula, for path parameterized $C^k$ curves c is known:

$T(t):=\dot{c}(t)$

Hence

$\stackrel{\sim}{T}(t)=\dot{\stackrel{\sim}{c}}(t)=\dot{c(\varphi(t))}=\dot{\varphi}(t)\cdot\dot{c}(\varphi(t))$

But now I do not see how to go on, to get to $T(t)$.
Do you have a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Path parametrized? This is a strange term. I would call it arclength-parametrized or parametrized at unit speed. At any rate, use a different letter, like $s\in [0,\ell]$, for the arclength, and write down the chain rule comparing differentiation with respect to $s$ and differentiation with respect to $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the correct term. I must say, that I improvised... Hmm, I do not think I get your hint right... Do you mean, I should also calculate $\dot{\stackrel{\sim}{c}}(s)$?

Comment: Probably better to write $d/ds$ and $d/dt$ so you can keep the two variables sorted out. :) Note that your definition of curvature is $\kappa = \|dT/ds\|$.

Comment: Excuse me, but I still do not quite know, what you mean. :( You want me to calculate $\stackrel{\sim}{T}(s)$?

Comment: $\tilde T(s(t)) = T(t)$, if you're paying careful attention to variables. Remember that you know how to find $s(t)$ by integrating $\|\dot c(t)\|$, and hence you know $ds/dt = \dot s(t)$.

Comment: Ah, I think now I get you. $s(t)=\int_0^s ||\dot{c}(t)|| dt$

Comment: Almost: $s(t) = \int_a^t \|\dot c(u)\|\,du$.